# create subfolder in subfolder and move file

Tags: applescript

i am new to this and am looking for help: i have a piece of code that is working but wanna extend it and can't make it work so far:

i have this to create a project folder in a chosen location, with two folders and two subfolders:

```
`set JobName to text returned of (display dialog "Please enter Project Name:" default answer "New_Project")
set loc to choose folder "Choose Parent Folder Location"

tell application "Finder"
set newfo to make new folder at loc with properties {name:JobName}
set targetFolder to make new folder at newfo with properties  {name:"01_folder"}
make new folder at targetFolder with properties {name:"01_sub1"}
set targetFolder to make new folder at newfo with properties {name:"02_folder"}
make new folder at targetFolder with properties {name:"02_sub1"}

end tell`
```

i have two questions: 
1. how can I create a subfolder in subfolder {name:"01_sub1"}?
2. how can I move a file into one of the folder that are being created?
(I know how to move to a fixed path but not one that is being chosen in the process of the same script)

i would be super thankful for any hints!
spoke

Answer (score 0):

You are already doing it in your other lines so I don't understand why you have problems. You have this line:

```
make new folder at targetFolder with properties {name:"01_sub1"}
```

Just change that to capture the folder variable like this...

```
set subFolder1 to make new folder at targetFolder with properties {name:"01_sub1"}
```

Then you can put a sub folder into that with...

```
set anotherSubFolder to make new folder at subFolder1 with properties {name:"another subfolder"}
```

Note you'll also capture that folder variable so all you need to do to move a file to it is...

```
move someFile to anotherSubFolder
```

All I'm showing you is using the same logic you've already used elsewhere in the code.

Comment: great, thank you so much for your help!!! the folder structure is working...only for moving the file I am still getting an error message...do I have to define someFile by name, path or in a separate line? thanks a million for helping me, I am quite new to this...